# AS3: diagonal movement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, game-physics

I'm programming a flash game, I made an array of points (x and y positions) that some movieclips must follow. Those movieclips have a certain speed (they make steps of 5 pixels for now). When I want to move them horizontally or vertically, everything's fine, I have to add or remove 5 pixels of those clips' x or y. But sometimes they have to move diagonally and now that's complicated.

What I'm doing:

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(nextPoint.y - this.y, nextPoint.x - this.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
var xstep:Number = Math.cos(angle) * this.speed;
var ystep:Number = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.speed, 2) - Math.pow(xstep, 2));

this.x += xstep;
this.y += ystep;
```

It's only a fraction of the code, but I think it's all you need.
Basically, this makes my movieclip do a little step (of this.speed (currently set to 5) pixels).

If the current point and the next point have the same y position, it works fine. When they don't, it doesn't work. The angle is right at first but it slowly decreases (while it should stay the same). I don't know if it's the angle that isn't computed the right way or if it's the x and y steps, but it's one of those, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(nextPoint.y - this.y, nextPoint.x - this.x);
var xstep:Number = Math.cos(angle) * this.speed;
var ystep:Number = Math.sin(angle) * this.speed;
```

Because `cos` operates on angles in *radians*, you don't need to convert to degrees.  Computing the y component of an angle uses `sin`, so it should be similar to x.  I'm not able to test this, but it's possible that `ystep` will be backwards and may need to be multiplied by `-1`.

Comment: I used the pythagorean theorem for the ystep at first, but I like your way better. It works now, all I had to do is _not_ change radians into degrees. Thank you, I'll remember it, haha.